# How do I change port using dotenv and skeltekit node-adapter in production?

Tags: node.js, svelte, dotenv, sveltekit

I have this in my `svelte.config.js` file but it appears to be ignored in production (it works fine with `npm run dev`)

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv-flow';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';


dotenv.config();

...
        adapter: adapter({
            out: './build',
            precompress: true
        }),
        vite: {
            ...
            server: {
                port: process.env.PORT || 3000
            }
        }
```

I do not see `dotenv` anywhere in the `build/` directory which means its ignoring `.env.local`

There are other environment variables my app needs as well its not just port.

My production app is started with systemd using `cd build && node index.js`

Answer (score 2):

Because I use systemd I have a script in `./bin/start.sh`

I am now passing `PORT` for now but the sveltekit build should handle this in my opinion.

start.sh:

```
. .env
. .env.local

PORT=${PORT} node build/index.js
```

Comment: [Issue 4296 - Consistent handling of environment variables]( https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4296)  
contains a "should work with .env" phrase.

So it could be fixed in a future version of SvelteKit

Comment: The nice thing about dotenv-flow is it supports